# FileStream.close() does not free file for other processes

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream, file-access

I have Following Code in a Page_Load called function. When the Page is loaded the first time after starting Visual Studio, everything works out fine.
But any other opening call to the File after that returns `IOException: "File is in use by another process"`, even when directly opening the File in VisualStudio Solution this Error is returned(of course not as Exception)

```
FileStream mailinglist_FileStream = new FileStream(@"\foobarFile.txt", FileMode.Open);
PeekingStreamReader mailinglist_Reader = new PeekingStreamReader(mailinglist_FileStream);
//Do some stuff with the file
mailinglist_FileStream.Close();
mailinglist_Reader.Close();
mailinglist_Reader.Dispose();
mailinglist_FileStream.Dispose();
```

Why is the file still locked? and why does fully restarting Visual Studio reset the File? 
when checking file-Properties it says:

> Build Action: Content
>   Copy to output directory: do not Copy

I am only reading this File. can i do something similiar to `adLockOptimistic`, so that multiple processes can access the File?

Comment: on side note: use the using statement instead of closing and disposing objects manually

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why is the file still locked? and why does fully restarting Visual
> Studio reset the File? when checking file-Properties it says [...]
> I don't know why the file is still locked: probably because your code fails before the stream is closed/disposed.

About *"why fully restarting Visual Studio [...]"*: because you may be using IIS Express or ASP.NET Dev Server whose are closed when you close the IDE, so locks on files are released since the process holding the locks is no longer running.

And about *"why is the file still locked?[...]*" it could be because the file stream isn't closed because sometimes the thread may not end successfully and the locks aren't released.

As other answer said, check how `using` block may avoid that `IDisposable` objects wouldn't be disposed:

```
// FileShare.ReadWrite will allow other processes 
// to read and write the target file even if other processes 
// are working with the same file
using var mailinglist_FileStream = new FileStream(@"\foobarFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileShare.ReadWrite);
using var mailinglist_Reader = new PeekingStreamReader(mailinglist_FileStream);
      // Do your stuff. Using blocks will call Dispose() for 
      // you even if something goes wrong, as it's equal to a try/finally!
```

> I am only reading this File. can i do something similiar to
> adLockOptimistic, so that multiple processes can access the File?

Yes, take a look at `File.Open` method and `FileShare` enumeration:

- `File.Open`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx
- `FileShare` enum: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx

Comment: @Matias Regarding your braces comment: "without extra { }" is a personal preference of using the language syntax. A single-statement block doesn't require enclosing braces. And the FileShare.ReadWrite will allow other processes access to the file, but it doesn't solve the problem of the file being left open. Nice example and good points, though.

Comment: Since C# 8.0 you can also use the handy [using declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration). `using var mailinglist_FileStream = new FileStream(@"\foobarFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileShare.ReadWrite);
using var mailinglist_Reader = new PeekingStreamReader(mailinglist_FileStream);
// Do your stuff.`

Answer (score 9):

Learn to use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(@"C:\somefile", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    ...
}
```

The `using` construct ensures that the file will be closed when you leave the block even if an exception is thrown.

Your problem might not be here, but somewhere else in your code. You'll have to go through all your code and look for places where you have opened files but not put it inside a `using` statement.

Answer (score 5):

An old question but unfortunately the given answers can be not applicable to the question.

The problem specifically in Windows lies in two aspects of Windows behavior:

a) when the handle to the file, opened for writing, is closed, the Microsoft Antimalware Service opens the file to check the newly written data for malware;

b) the OS itself keeps the file opened for some time after all handles to it are closed. This time can be from seconds to many minutes depending on the nature of the file and other factors.

We saw this problem many times in our products and had to provide special support for this case - our kernel-mode attempts to close the file as soon as the last handle to it is closed.

Comment: Ahhhh. Is the best way to handle it literally just a loop with a try-catch or did you find better ways? I need to move the file shortly (preferably immediately) after I close the file stream but I've been running into this issue on slower computers.

Comment: @AlecPetersen Our products work "on the other side" (we provide virtual filesystems and  filter drivers). On the filesystem level, it is possible to ask the system to release a file. But even a filter driver cannot do this :(.

Answer (score 0):

You only need read access. For some reason, FileStream opens for write as well, so just specify read-only:

`FileStream (FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)`

Works for me in a similar situation in Powershell (which uses dotnet classes).

Comment: this suggestion is basically already covered in the accepted answer..

Comment: @Vogel612: The accepted answer talks about locking, VS, IIS and correctly answers the original question _why_ it is locked. The example there shows how to open for read _and_ write, however the original code only needs reading. And yes, it points to the enum documentation, whereas I just show the one line to do. Some like it short and to the point.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `using` blocks, it may not fix your lock problem, but it is better form for disposable objects.

```
using (FileStream mailinglist_FileStream = new FileStream(@"\foobarFile.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (PeekingStreamReader mailinglist_Reader = new PeekingStreamReader(mailinglist_FileStream))
    {
        ...            
    }
}
```

Also, try closing `mailinglist_Reader` before `mailinglist_FileStream`.

Comment: the funny thing is, after changing the order, the Page_Load works, but my catch(IOException) BLock still gets executed

Comment: Call of `Stream.Close` in using block is redundant.

Comment: What exception are you getting, the same one? Try commenting out the two `Close();` lines as they are probably called by `using`.

Comment: You can put multiple `using`s at the same indentation level and have just one set of `{}`s.